# reactjs - Import a dynamic file in render() method

Tags: reactjs

I've got a question about importing a dynamic file path in `reactjs`.
I already know, that I can import a file / image like this:

```
import pdfImage from '../images/pdf.svg';
```

Now I wanto to import a file from an object given from the props. I have relative file path in my object saved i.e.

`documents/1_1_DEU_DE.pdf`

The issue is, that on build, the path to the file looks like this i.e. of the pdf image above.

> /static/media/pdf.3fa92281.svg

so I'm searching for something similar to this:

```
render() {
    import pdfFile from '../' + this.props.termsAndCondition.pdfDocument;
    return (
        <li>
            <a href={pdfFile} target="_blank">
                <img src={pdfImage}></img> 
                {this.props.termsAndCondition.language}
            </a>
        </li>
    );
}
```

Of course, I know, I can put the files instead of the `src` folder to the `public` folder, but is this recommended?
I'm sure there is a solution to my problem, but all my researches did not get an answer to me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it’s a static file you may be could put an absolute path including domain http://...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the answer. I can use `require` to import files dynamically.

```
render() {
   let pdfFile = require('../' + this.props.termsAndCondition.pdfDocument);
   return (
      <li>
         <a href={pdfFile} target="_blank" className="link">
            <img src={pdfImage} className="phoneMain"></img> 
            {this.props.termsAndCondition.language}
         </a>
      </li>
   );
}
```