# How to pass a variable in a file path React JS

Tags: reactjs

So I have this pdf file import link:

```
import pdf from '../Files/file-1.pdf'
```

but I want that name of the file "file-1" to be a variable cause its gonna change from one user to another so is it possible to do pass a variable in the path
something like:

```
const filename = "file-1.pdf"
import pdf from `../File/${filename}` /*ofc this method doesn't 
work for many reasons but I just wanted to explain my question*/
```

Comment: [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042301/reactjs-import-a-dynamic-file-in-render-method) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: you might want to checkout [dynamic import](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports) which is a syntax for giving a **Promise** that resolves after importing some dynamic links. The code could be inside of a `useEffect` or you might use `React Query`

Comment: yes @PhilipClark it worked, post that as an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042301/reactjs-import-a-dynamic-file-in-render-method) might help.

## From Thread:

I've got the answer. I can use require to import files dynamically.

```
const dynamicFile = require('../somepath/' + someVar);
```